# Tell if browser is chrome running on windows or mac/linux

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows, macos, google-chrome

Is there an easy way to tell if chrome is under windows or mac/linux?

I have a webbapplication where the browser behaves different when running it on MAC and PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is.  Hope the below code will help.

```
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win")!=-1){
     //It is Windows
}else if(navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Linux")!=-1){
     //It is Linux
}else if((navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac")!=-1){
     //It is Mac
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function testOS(){

 var mac=navigator.userAgent.match(/(Mac)/i)?true:false;
 if($.browser.webkit){
   if(mac){
          //Mac Code
   }
   else{
         //window code
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: $.browser isnt supported in newer jquery versions?